# How to insert images directly in openXML document.xml

Tags: xml, xslt, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to call local images in openXML and convert XML to Word with those images using XSLT, I would like to insert the images directly instead of calling in document_rels file.

I used the below tag to call the image 'blue_hills.jpg in C' drive

```
   <w:pict>
    <v:shape id="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:250; height:200">
     <v:imagedata src="c:\Blue_hills.jpg"/>
    </v:shape>
   </w:pict>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it that way. Images are converted to binary and added as a image part to document.  The attribute src for imagedata in your XML is invalid. It just stores the relationship id for the image part.

This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmahugh/archive/2006/12/10/images-in-open-xml-documents.aspx) explains the Open XML for document with image.

Here is an [example](http://tepehughes.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/adding-and-image-to-a-word-2007-document-using-open-xml-sdk-v2-0/) to insert image programmatically.